# Mootools disable a link tag

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

I was trying to disable a link tag with CSS but only works with Mozilla

```
.inactive-link{
   pointer-events: none !important;
   cursor: default !important;
}
```

So no I will try to disable the link by javascript, I am ussing mootools. Does anyone know how to do it? I tried this but only works in mozilla, thanks in advance!

```
<a href="http://....." class="inactive-link">Here is my text</a>

    $('.inactive-link').addEvent('click', function (e) {
        e = new Event(e).preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Which mootools version do you use? `e.stop()` should so it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this in plain old Javascript.

```
<a href = "http://www.google.com" onclick = "return false;">Link</a>
```

Now the link goes nowhere!